# Can a husband ask his wife to pierce her belly for his own pleasure?

Tags: nikah, husband-wife, love, wife, modesty

Assalamu alaikum dear readers,

I just wanted to know if I can ask my wife for belly piercing to impress me and not show others.

It is only between me and her for my pleasure and to preserve her beauty to keep her my ultimate(to prevent interest on others).

This is especially during love making or wearing swimsuit on private areas..... [Like on sexy panty and belly dance outfit, maybe a swimsuit].

NON PENETRATING clips are also fine.

BTW PLEASE **DON'T** **JUDGE** HER BECAUSE SHE'S **MODEST**

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem if it's between husband and wife. Both should try their best to pleasure themselves. But it should be private and make sure none can see you.

"Who guard their chastity,except with their spouses or their slaves ––with these they are not to blame."(surah mu'minun,5-6)

Comment: so its 100% yes? well thanks..